# Fabric.JS with Node.JS - Exporting as PNG/JPEG

Tags: javascript, node.js, png, fabricjs, fs

So I'm just messing around with Fabric.JS **for Node.JS, not for the web**, and I've managed to make a Static Canvas, and put a rectangle on it. Time to export. Here's my code for the creation of the canvas and adding of a rectangle:

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, {width: 200, height: 200})
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  fill: "red"
})
canvas.add(rect)
```

Here's everything I've tried for exporting the image:

```
//Creates a PNG file that isn't generated correctly. It's as if it's corrupt. No program can open it
canvas.createPNGStream().on("data", function (chunk) {
  fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.png").write(chunk)
})
```

---

```
//Causes a crash
canvas.createJPEGStream().on("data", function (chunk) {
  fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.jpeg").write(chunk)
})

Error:
C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\canvas\lib\jpegstream.js:44
    canvas[method](options.bufsize, options.quality, options.progressive, function(err, chunk){
                  ^

TypeError: canvas[method] is not a function
    at C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\canvas\lib\jpegstream.js:44:19
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

---

```
//Same thing as first try^^, except it's a JPEG
canvas.createJPEGStream({quality: 100}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.jpeg"))
```

---

```
//This one makes the PNG file, but when it's opened, its 100% transparent. That's it. The rectangle I added isn't there. Canvas size is correct, however
canvas.createPNGStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.png"))
```

---

Note: `fabric.Canvas(null, {width: 200, height: 200})` also seems to work exactly the same as `StaticCanvas`, in this case

Note 2: This code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.createCanvasForNode(200, 200)
```

results in this error:

```
var canvas = new fabric.createCanvasForNode(200, 200)
             ^

TypeError: fabric.createCanvasForNode is not a constructor
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\index.js:31:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:330:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:293:17)
    at WebSocketClient.internalOnMessage (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\uws\uws.js:103:17)
    at native.client.group.onMessage (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\uws\uws.js:57:15)
```

---

Is there something I'm missing here? None of these methods seem to be working and it's about all I could find on Google. What's the correct way of exporting an image? It can be PNG or JPEG/JPG, preferably PNG, but JPEG/JPG will do. Any common format really.

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4) **Fabric on Node.js**

Comment: @Durga yup I've already tried the PNGStream (attempt 1 in the question)

Comment: To create canvas use `var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(200, 200);` there is total code in that tutorial try that.

Comment: @Durga just edited my question to have a note at the bottom about the error `fabric.createCanvasForNode` causes

Comment: I see, its removed, and `new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, {width: 200, height: 200})` this will work. will check the rest, and let you know.

Comment: @Durga `fabric.Canvas` also works identically to `StaticCanvas` in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. `canvas.createPNGStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.png"))` does actually work. The reason it was completely empty, is because it looks like `canvas.add()` isn't an instantanious action. All I did to figure this out was a `setTimeout()` before outputting the file. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I use this sample code from `node-canvas` and it works

```
const fs = require('fs')
const out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/test.png')
const stream = canvas.createPNGStream()
stream.pipe(out)
out.on('finish', () =>  console.log('The PNG file was created.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this [tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4) ,which  [shared by Durga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343063/fabric-js-with-node-js-exporting-as-png-jpeg#comment87702864_50343063),  You forgot to use, `canvas.renderAll();`

Adding this fixed the problem for me.

full code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, {width: 200, height: 200})
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  fill: "red"
})
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.createPNGStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./output.png"))
```