# FabricJS convert json to png

Tags: javascript, node.js, fabricjs, node-canvas

I have created the following image as fabricjs-json:

[image]

The json looks like the following:

```
{
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "objects": [
        {
            "type": "circle",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": "100",
            "top": "100",
            "width": "60",
            "height": "60",
            "fill": "#e53e3e",
            "name": "a",
            "radius": "30",
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": "0"
        },
        {
            "type": "triangle",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": "80",
            "top": "229.13",
            "fill": "#e0da2e",
            "name": "b",
            "height": "100",
            "width": "100",
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": "0"
        },
        {
            "type": "rect",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": "303.02",
            "top": "69.96",
            "width": "50",
            "height": "50",
            "fill": "#4976d0",
            "name": "c",
            "rx": "0",
            "ry": "0",
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": "0"
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": "272.23",
            "top": "287.63",
            "width": "400",
            "height": "400",
            "scaleX": "0.58",
            "scaleY": "0.58",
            "name": "d",
            "rx": "0",
            "ry": "0",
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": "0",
            "src": "https:\/\/picsum.photos\/id\/1014\/400",
            "crossOrigin": null
        },
        {
            "type": "textbox",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": "210.97",
            "top": "100",
            "width": "265.14180221557615",
            "height": "25.99",
            "fill": "#000000",
            "angle": "33.4",
            "name": "e",
            "text": "This awesome image",
            "textAlign": "left",
            "fontSize": "23",
            "charSpacing": "7",
            "lineHeight": "1.16",
            "fontWeight": "400",
            "fontFamily": "Inter",
            "fontStyle": "normal",
            "textBackgroundColor": null,
            "maxHeight": "487",
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": "20"
        }
    ],
    "background": "#24bd0f"
}
```

I created the following script to convert the json to an image:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.png');

let jsonstr = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/json/test_json.json', 'utf-8');
let json = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, { width: 500, height: 500 });

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {

    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);

    var dataUrlOutput = canvas.toDataURL(); // png is default format
    console.log(dataUrlOutput)
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/output/output.png', dataUrlOutput, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "jsonToImage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.9.3",
    "fabric": "^5.2.4"
  }
}
```

However, when opening the image I get:

[image]

I created the following sandbox to parse the json:

[Codesandbox Example - JSONtoIMAGE](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-lalande-d6qn3b?file=/output.png:0-68082)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I checked the `dataUrlOutput`  from the script and I get the following:

[image]

As you can see half of the elements are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a few things going on, namely the formatting of your JSON, rendering the canvas, and saving the file in Node.

#### Formatting your JSON

The numbers in your json file are enclosed in quotes (e.g. `"left": "100"`), while for those numerical values, fabric.js expects them not to be in quotes (e.g. `"left": 100`). When there are quotes around the numbers, fabric.js seems to quasi-load some objects, but not others.

When you're saving your canvas as JSON, you can use `JSON.stringify` to ensure that the formatting is preserved. For example, `JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON())`;

#### Rendering the canvas

You're calling `canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)`, which creates a new function but doesn't call it. It should just be `canvas.renderAll()`.

#### Saving an image

Saving a data url directly as a text file does not create an image in an encoded binary file. While you could use the data url to create a binary file (like from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335500/)), fabric.js adds some convenience functions to save a file, namely `canvas.createPNGStream()`.

It looks something like this (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101496/)):

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.png');
var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
stream.pipe(out);
```

#### All together

With the modified JSON and code, the results look something like this:

Your data file, `'json/test_json.json'`

```
{
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "objects": [
        {
            "type": "circle",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": 100,
            "top": 100,
            "width": 60,
            "height": 60,
            "fill": "#e53e3e",
            "name": "a",
            "radius": 30,
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": 0
        },
        {
            "type": "triangle",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": 80,
            "top": 229.13,
            "fill": "#e0da2e",
            "name": "b",
            "height": 100,
            "width": 100,
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": 0
        },
        {
            "type": "rect",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": 303.02,
            "top": 69.96,
            "width": 50,
            "height": 50,
            "fill": "#4976d0",
            "name": "c",
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": 0
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": 272.23,
            "top": 287.63,
            "width": 400,
            "height": 400,
            "scaleX": 0.58,
            "scaleY": 0.58,
            "name": "d",
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": 0,
            "src": "https:\/\/picsum.photos\/id\/1014\/400",
            "crossOrigin": null
        },
        {
            "type": "textbox",
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "originX": "center",
            "originY": "center",
            "left": 210.97,
            "top": 100,
            "width": 265.14180221557615,
            "height": 25.99,
            "fill": "#000000",
            "angle": 33.4,
            "name": "e",
            "text": "This awesome image",
            "textAlign": "left",
            "fontSize": 23,
            "charSpacing": 7,
            "lineHeight": 1.16,
            "fontWeight": 400,
            "fontFamily": "Inter",
            "fontStyle": "normal",
            "textBackgroundColor": null,
            "maxHeight": 487,
            "stroke": null,
            "padding": 20
        }
    ],
    "background": "#24bd0f"
}
```

And your node.js program:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.png');

let jsonstr = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/json/test_json.json', 'utf-8');
let json = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, { width: 500, height: 500 });

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
    stream.pipe(out);
    out.on('finish', function () {
        // do something here
    });
});
```

##### More reading:

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4 (the 'Fabric on Node.js' section)